# Motorcycle won't start the second time. Flooding?

Tags: motorcycle, starting, carburetor

My `1990 Suzuki DR350S` starts pretty easily and runs fine, but once I have started it up I can't start it the next time unless I let it sit for like an hour.

It seems to me like it is flooded. Because if I remove all the gas from the carb using the drain, and then try to start it again, it starts pretty easy. What can I do to prevent the motorcycle from flooding? Or is that even the problem?

Comment: Any issues (cut out, sputtering) while riding? Could be a stuck float in the carb. You can try tapping it (the carb's bowl) lightly with the plastic end of a screwdriver to loosen it a bit.

Comment: My KTM is like that. In your case id start with a carb strip and soak the components in carb cleaner, then clean thoroughly. Id clean and check fuel tap, lines filters etc. Anything that restricts fuel or air could result in a lean or rich condition. Just as too much air or fuel can also.

Comment: Another possibility is coil or cdi being affecter by heat. You could try swapping them to see if you could rule them out.

Comment: Has this bike been sitting for any length of time? Is this a sudden problem or has it gotten gradually worse over time? When was the last time any fuel treatment was used?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the procedure I used for starting the bike cold definitely does not work when the bike is warm.

My typical cold start procedure was to give the bike several soft primer kicks just to turn the engine over several times. Then pull the choke and give it 2-3 hard kicks, and by the 3rd or 4th kick it would start up.

What was happening is that after work around 5pm once the sun was out and the bike was already warm, I was following the same procedure. This was too much gas for the bike and I was flooding it, making it harder to start. My procedure for starting the bike warm now is to give it a few soft primer kicks, then just kick it over once or twice to start it without the choke.

The bike doesn't flood anymore now and it is easy to start :)